# Capture first or second instance of match

Tags: javascript, regex

The text looks like this:

`I want to spread out the running over the week.{d}2020/01/01{d} {d}2020/02/02{d}`

I am using this regex to capture the data within `{d}` markup.

`/{d}.*?{d}/gm`

However, this selects each group. How can I select only one (say first) instance of `{d}` match. That is, how do I only select the first `{d}2020/01/01{d}`.

And out of curiosity, how would that regex be different if I wanted to select the second match `{d}2020/02/02{d}`.

Comment: 1st: Remove the `g` from `/g` 2nd: .match[2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match only first block just don't use `g` flag:

```
/{d}[\d\/]+{d}/
```

To match last block use a greedy `.*` before it and capture it in group #1:

```
/.*({d}[\d\/]+{d})/
```

To get `N`th match of this block:

```
/^(?:.*?{d}[\d\/]+{d}){2}.*?({d}[\d\/]+{d})/
```

Your match is in group #1.

Or else use `/{d}[\d\/]+{d}/g` for match and get Nth element from resulting array.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ow7nB/1)

Answer (score 1):

To get the first one, remove the `g` from the `/g`

```js
const re = /{d}(.*?){d}/m

const str = `I want to spread out the running over the week.{d}2020/01/01{d} {d}2020/02/02{d}`
const match = re.exec(str);
console.log(match[1]);
```

To get more

Loop over the matches and later access the one you want

```js
const re = /{d}(.*?){d}/gm

const str = `I want to spread out the running over the week.{d}2020/01/01{d} {d}2020/02/02{d}`
const matches = str.matchAll(re);
const dates = []
for (const match of matches) {
  dates.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(dates);
console.log(dates[1]); // the second
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\s` to check for word boundaries: `({d}.*?{d})\s`

See: https://regex101.com/r/Ty8IzV/2

To match the 2nd group: `\s({d}.*?{d})`

See: https://regex101.com/r/075weF/1/